# A train loss and a validation loss are same

Tags: python, keras

I used fully connected layers via keras api to predict regression values.
To generalize the model, I plotted train and validation loss. I wanted the plot to show me a point that the validation loss is higher than train loss.
However, both loss values were almost similar and no change.

I was wondering.

1. Is that model trained well?
2. If the model trained well, how can i interpret the loss plot?
3. the model performance isn't good. so what should i do for improving the performance about the model?

Answer (score 0):

As we all learned, the validation error are often higher than training loss. So you might feel strange when both of them are the same. In my opinion, your model probably hasn't been well trained. You will still have to try more parameters and have them (and corresponding error on test data set) recorded in a file to help you find the best parameter.

One simple way of finding better parameters is to use a for-loop over one certain parameter with the others fixed, and then record them like below

```
List = [parameter_1, parameter_2, parameter_3]
Name = 'parameter_1, parameter_2, parameter_3 \n'
f = open('training-log.csv','a')
f.write(Name)
for i in List:
    f.write('{},'.format(str(i)))
f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

Hope this can help you.